# Why is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion, good-questions, scope

[Does the Disney Dining plan impose any restrictions on the food I can order?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/whats-good-and-bad-about-disney-dining-plan)

it's about travelling experience to disney world

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to know about the Dining plan? You must be asking this with some thought in mind, presumably?

Comment: I just want to know if travelers had good experience with it. Disney offers it (sometimes for free) as part of hotel stays. But you know, maybe the lines are too long, or selection is bad, or the restrictions are too strict....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> what are the advantages and disadvantages of Disney dining plan? This sounds like good option (especially when it's free with promotions) but i am worried about locking myself into what i can order.

This is a great example of a question where you seem to know what you want to ask, but just can't quite bring yourself to ask it...

You already know the advantages; I'm sure the advertising material is pretty clear on them. You *suspect* you know what the catch is too: lock-in. So you don't really need to ask, "what are the advantages / disadvantages", and set yourself up for answers that don't even answer your question...

**Be specific**. Ask if the Disney plan locks you into pre-planned meals. You can always broaden your question later, if necessary, or ask other questions...

Comment: Great data for the FAQ

Answer (score 5):

firstly, I apologise for not giving a fuller explanation when I closed the question as off-topic. Flying with 9-10 layovers from TPE-SIN-DEL-LHR so a bit sleep-deprived.

Travel discount programmes are definitely on-topic on Travel.SE. However, the question in its original form seemed to have a very tenuous link to travel - I wasn't aware that this is something associated with stay at Disney hotels and it just sounded - in its initial form - as some sort of discount card for a very specific Disney-operated theme park / resort restaurant / chain. Just like, I'd say, a question about any discount card would be off-topic. Little knowledge, dangerous thing, etc. Yeah.

I see the question has been edited to make it clearer now. I'll reopen then question, I apologise for not explaining clearly at the outset and for taking this long to log back in. I hope you get an answer to the question, and I'm sorry that one of your initial experiences with Travel.SE was bad.

Answer (score 4):

I guess some might feel that it's a very tenuous travel link.  It'd be like asking what's good about BMW, because you can travel with one.  I don't know enough about it myself, but it sounds like some sort of club card to get food discounts at Disney restaurants?

Comment: so travel discount programs are off topic?

Comment: Is it a travel discount program? I don't know enough about it, I was just hypothesizing.  I wouldn't think so - it depends on the wording - 'what's good?' gets a discussion, as it's subjective, and as per the [faq], subjective open discussion questions are not desirable - best to perhaps ask something which will get a specific answer.  Like with the BMW - 'which BMW motorcycle is more suited to overland travel in Russia' which could elicit an answer like the details of the bikes used in 'The Long Way Round'.

Comment: My personal feeling is it should have been closed for being too vague and open, rather than off-topic, but I am sure when the moderator that closed it comes online he'll be able to explain.